# Testing HTML 5 form validations when using simple_form Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, simple-form

I'm using devise and simple_form for my todo list app . Now , I have the following code for my users/edit.html.erb

```
<%= content_for :title,'Edit profile' %>
<h2>Edit profile</h2>
<%= simple_form_for current_user, class: 'form-horizontal' do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :nick_name %>
  <%= f.submit 'Update profile' %>
<% end %>
```

My user.rb looks like this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
 attr_accessible :email,:nick_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
 validates :nick_name, presence: true    # the other fields already validated by devise
 has_many :lists , dependent: :destroy
end
```

Now, when I click on submit button with an empty nick_name field ,I get a popup kind of alert . It's not like a normal browser alert ,I think its a HTML5 feature . I get this message `Please fill out this field` as a popup below the empty field . I have disabled javascript, but it still shows the same message .
This is my nick_name input field :

```
<input class="string required" id="user_nick_name" name="user[nick_name]" required="required" size="50" type="text">
```

Now, when I remove the presence validation for nick_name in my model , this popup doesn't appear .When validation line is commented out ,

```
<input class="string optional" id="user_nick_name" name="user[nick_name]" size="50" type="text">
```

Is simple_form doing some behind the scenes magic ?

Since this popup doesnt show any trace of html code , How to test for this validation in capybara/rspec ?

Comment: That is an html5 feature, only the attribute is needed and of course support of the browser.

Comment: Ok , how do I test it using capybara ?

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using the `required="required"` attribute, this triggers an HTML5 validation.

To test this:

`message = find("#user_nick_name").native.attribute("validationMessage")
expect(message).to eq "Please fill out this field"`

Comment: This checks that the field is invalid, but not that the message is being displayed—it's present whenever the field has an invalid value. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/validationMessage).

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can test it by finding html attribute `required="required"` with the following code example:

```
expect(page).to have_xpath("//input[@required='required']")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ..But is there any way to test the message that appears ? Or atleast to check that the form doesn't submit ?

Comment: This won't test that the form is actually validating.