# How to test in Capybara that a page does not change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

I have a simple form consisting of a text field and a submit button, used for searching. I want to test in Capybara, that if the text field is empty, nothing heppens upon clicking on the submit button or pressing enter. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Hm, good question. I would maybe think of what I want my app to behave like. Usually you want something to happen. Otherwise the User would not know if something is wrong with the app or if he made a mistake.

Think in terms of the User. Why would I interact with your form if I expected it to do nothing.

```
scenario 'As a User When I submit an empty form Then it tells me what I can do useful' do

  visit '/path_to_your_page'

  click_button 'Your submit button' 

  expect(page).to have_content 'Please enter something I want'
end
```

Ah, now I get your idea. You mean like google for example. When I enter nothing and press enter nothing happes. And you want to write a test for that case.

Hm, I actually don't know how google for example does that. I could imagine that they only allow to submit requests if at least one character is entered. I guess it is done with javascript in frontend.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for the sake of providing an answer, the Capybara session matchers work well to make sure the page hasn't changed:

```
  visit register_path

  within 'form.register' do
    fill_in 'Username', with: username
    fill_in 'Password', with: password
    find_button('Register').click
  end

  expect(page.has_current_path?(register_path)).to be_truthy
```

You can also use another method to compare it against the url/path that was visited at the start of the test, even though it's a bit redundant compared to the above:

```
current_page = page.current_url                 # can use current_path too
expect(page.current_url).to eq(current_page)
```

If you want to test validations specifically, you may also want to check that validations are being checked instead of trying to target the error [Testing HTML5 Form Validations when using simple_form Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384428/testing-html-5-form-validations-when-using-simple-form-rails).